# iOS set BackButton in the current ViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin.ios, back-button, uinavigationitem

How can I change the Back-Button of the **currently displayed** ViewController?
Configuring the BackButtonItem effects the BackButton of the next ViewController, instead of the currently shown.

e.g.: I have two ViewControllers VCA and VCB. I navigate from VCA to VCB and want to style the BackButton thats shown on VCB. I want to hide the title and set custom icons for normal and highlighted state.

```
public class VCB : ViewControllerBase
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var btn = new UIBarButtonItem("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
        // TODO: set the Icon
        NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = btn;
    }
}
```

Do I have to implement my own BackButton and set it as LeftBarButton, or can I achieve this somehow with the standard BackButton .

Answer (score 0):

if the viewController already has a `BarButtonItem` in the View,you should be able to use `this.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem` and change its properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
UIBarButtonItem backButton = new UIBarButtonItem("< Back",UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(backButton, false);
```

Comment: I know that this is working. My question targeted the standard back button explicitly. But I found no other way to solve it except the `SetLeftButtonItem`.